# What's the essential bandwidth of the unit step function?

Tags: fourier, bandwidth

The Fourier spectrum is in the Figure, how to find the essential bandwidth?
[image: The Fourier spectrum]

Comment: How do you define 'essential bandwidth'? Anyway, I think that in this case it will be hard to find a useful definition which does NOT yield $\infty$ as a result. As a sidenote, you can't define the magnitude of this function because the term $\delta^2(\omega)$ has no meaning.

Comment: The unit step function is time-scale invariant, which means there is no way to define a unique time scale, and as such also no unique bandwidth of any kind. Your question is therefore absolutely meaningless.

Comment: Also apart from the point Matt correctly states, your plot is quite wrong too.

Comment: @Jazzmaniac, i like how the function turns up a little as "$|w|$" increases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there **can be no** essential bandwidth of the unit step function.  defining such would lead you to self-contradiction.

suppose you have a function $x(t)$ which has Fourier Transform

$$ X(f) = \int\limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty} x(t) e^{-j 2 \pi f t} \ dt $$

and from $X(f)$, you defined some consistent measure of bandwidth $B_x$ in such a way that is independent of the amplitude of $X$ and is dimensionally consistent with $f$.

now suppose you scale the time argument of $x(t)$ to speed it up or slow it down:

$$ y(t) = x(a t) \quad \text{for } a > 0 $$

we know that the the Fourier Transform of $y(t)$ would be

$$ Y(f) = \frac{1}{a} X\left(\frac{f}{a} \right) $$

and the bandwidth of $Y(f)$ defined in the same manner as $B_x$ would be

$$ B_y = a B_x $$

so, suppose $a>1$, then you speed up $x(t)$ by the factor $a$ and the bandwidth is increased by the same factor.

but if you *"speed up"* (or *slow down*) the unit step function, you still have the **very same** unit step function:

$$ u(t) = u(a t) \quad \text{for } a > 0 $$

where

$$ u(t) \triangleq \begin{cases}
1, & \text{if } t > 0 \\
0, & \text{if } t < 0 \\
\end{cases} $$

so scaling time for the unit step does not change it, yet **if** it had a bandwidth, scaling the time **must** change that bandwidth.  a contradiction results.